# Google cloud_sql_proxy keep my connection alive

Tags: gcloud, cloud-sql-proxy

I'm making a connection between a Google Compute Engine instance and a Google Cloud SQL instance, using the Cloud SQL Proxy.
Using [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-compute-engine) tutorial,  I have managed to establish a connection by running this command:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>=tcp:3306
```

However, when I quit the terminal instance I used to enter the above command the connection is lost.

How can i keep the connection alive throughout?

Comment: Can you rephrase "However, when I quit the terminal instance I used to enter the above command the connection is lost.". It's difficult to understand what you mean.

Comment: Keep in mind that to connect with the Cloud SQL instance using the Cloud SQL Proxy, the cloud_sql_proxy must be running in it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the process of cloud_sql_proxy to run as long as the Google Compute Engine (GCE) instance is running, just make the process run in the background.
For that you just add the '&' character in the end of your command, so i would go like this:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>=tcp:3306&
```

This way, as along as you don't stop the GCE instance, you can ssh to it and connect to your Cloud SQL instance (with INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME) with the Cloud SQL Proxy being used.